# Phone hangups and client realises

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, twilio, phone-call, twilio-api

I'm using Twilio API to make some calls from browser to phones and I have one question? Can the client realize when the user hangups his/her phone, raising an event and changing something in the view with js?

I'm trying to implement a single but user-friendly call/hangup modal to make the calls using twilio js library.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can register an event listener on a [Twilio Connection](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/client/connection) object to achieve that:

```
var connection = Twilio.Device.connect();

connection.disconnect(function(conn) {
  console.log("the call has ended");
});
```